# How is whereis ordering its results?

Tags: apt, bash

When running `whereis apt` I get a result set which looks like this:

```
apt: /usr/bin/apt /usr/lib/apt /etc/apt /usr/share/man/man8/apt.8.gz
```

When I then run `which apt` I get

```
/usr/bin/apt
```

which is the first result of the command above. 
I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204433/220514) that this is no coincidence, and it is related to the `$PATH` variable. So I ran `echo $PATH` and got:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Then I touched a file named `apt` in `/bin` and ran `which apt` again - with no changes happend, altough `whereis apt` changed to:

```
apt: /usr/bin/apt /usr/lib/apt /bin/apt /etc/apt /usr/share/man/man8/apt.8.gz
```

That led me to the conclusion that the `$PATH` environment maybe isn't everything? Can someone shed light on this issue? Where is `whereis` getting its information from?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you ran `which python` and got the result `/usr/bin/apt` instead of `/usr/bin/python`. Also, for output, you should use four spaces in front of the output, not `>`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, and it's not clear what you were trying to do in the first place, but try using `type` instead of `which`. It may give more detail - in this case about whether the binary is hashed. And did you make /bin/apt executable?

Comment: I think the order is `binary`,`source`, and `manuals`. See `man whereis`

Comment: In any respect I think it is wisest to run `which` rather than `whereis` or `locate`. On the nominated close vote as "unclear" the question may need massaging but I think the relative intent is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure whether you're asking about `whereis` or `which`, so I'm just going to address both.

## `whereis`

> `whereis`  locates  the binary, source and manual files for the
>   specified command names. (…) [It] attempts to locate the desired
>   program in the standard Linux places, and in the places specified by
>   `$PATH` and `$MANPATH`.
>   (…)
>   The easiest way to know what paths are in use is to add the `-l` listing option.
>   <sub>Source: `man whereis`</sub>

Run `whereis -l` to get a list of paths the program uses. By default it searches for binary, source and manual files, you can change that behaviour with the `-b`, `-s` and `-m` options, e.g.

```
$ whereis -m apt
apt: /usr/share/man/man8/apt.8.gz
$ whereis -b apt
apt: /usr/bin/apt /usr/lib/apt /etc/apt
```

Unlike `which` (see below) `whereis` *doesn't* test whether the file is executable when searching binaries, that's why `touch /bin/apt` alters its output.

## `which`

> `which`  returns  the  pathnames (…) by searching the PATH for
>   executable files matching the names of the arguments.
>   <sub>Source: `man which`</sub>

#### What `which` does

I take it `which` does essentially the same as this `find` command:

```
IFS=':'; find $PATH -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -name "SEARCH"
```

It searches every directory present in `PATH` for executable files named `SEARCH`, e.g. for `apt`:

```
$ which apt
/usr/bin/apt
$ IFS=':'; find $PATH -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -name "apt"
/usr/bin/apt
```

#### Why your attempt failed

By default `which` only prints the *first* match from the `PATH` directories, i.e. the file that gets executed. With `touch /bin/apt` you did create a file matching the name constraint, but you forgot to make it executable and you didn't issue `which` to output `a`ll matches. Let's try that again:

```
$ touch /bin/apt
$ chmod +x /bin/apt
$ which -a apt
/usr/bin/apt
/bin/apt
$ IFS=':'; find $PATH -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -name "apt"
/usr/bin/apt
/bin/apt
```

Comment: A POSIX-compliant alternative to `find ${PATH//:/ } ...` that also works with path names that contain spaces is `IFS=':'; find $PATH ...`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26784/47852 for more.

Comment: it was late at night and my concentration wasnt that high. my initial attempt was to "overwrite" the apt command. So I thought if I create a shellscript on some place which is within the path-variable i would see `which` putting out my shellscript, but somehow I got confused. You answered my question perfectly, thanks

Comment: You're welcome! `IFS=':' find $PATH ...` is not the same as `IFS=':'; find $PATH ...`. Note the semicolon placement! The latter sets `IFS` as a *shell variable* to influence variable expansion in *subsequent* command(s), while the former sets `IFS` as an *environment variable* for the newly created `find` process *after* all other variables in the same command were expanded. Of course you can use a line break instead of a semicolon.